# Mat sort is not applied in mat table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have applied mat-sort looking into amswers from stack overflow,but i am not able to apply it properly.Please help
Here is the stackblitz example of my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/notification.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `MatSort` view child to the `sort` property of the table's data source, once the view child is initialized.

Add the following method in your component class -

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Comment: can you help me with another issue in angular,This is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66783850/rows-disappear-in-mat-table-when-i-filter-first-and-then-group-the-table

Comment: @Zoro Sorry, I could not.