# rows disappear in mat table when i filter first and then group the table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, grouping, mat-table

Grouping in mat-table works fine when I don't filter it.
When filtered or put focus on search bar, the table gets filtered but then if I ungroup it, the rows of mat table disappear.
Please help me with a solution which groups or ungroups the table even after I filter it.
This problem occurs even while grouping when I put focus on filter search bar first.
I think the problem is with filter predicate when I setup filter for search bar.

Here is the working stack blitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/xwcnz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Your solution is not working

Comment: Stackblitz link does not work anymore. This is the reason StackOverflow says please put the code in here, because otherwise, parts of a question or a solution may get lost and the whole question gets mindless.

Answer (score 0):

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/notification-grouping-ekkevt?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

I've removed your filter assignment and then it's working.

```
this.dataSource.filter = performance.now().toString();
```

And I'm confused. What is `performance` anyway?

Anyways, I think your filtering and grouping both are working perfectly now.

Comment: But then you cant expand or collapse the group header

Comment: rows in the table still disappear in your stackblitz when we put focus on search  and then group it

Comment: Yeah. It reappears only after new key input.

Comment: this happens in my stackblitz as well